# how to set the Storage Access API?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-shell

[image]
When I test my app using a web preview, it shows the above page.

I do not know how to install it? Set? `Storage Access API`

Where to install `Storage Access API`?

Comment: if you click your mouse where it says "click to begin" what happens?

Comment: I have already click that link

but nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

Before you can use the Cloud Shell these are steps you should follow:

1. In the Google Cloud console, on the project selector page, select or [create a Google Cloud project](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects).

**Note:**

> If you don't plan to keep the resources that you create in this procedure, create a project instead of selecting an existing project. After you finish these steps, you can delete the project, removing all resources associated with the project.
> [Go to project selector](https://console.cloud.google.com/projectselector2/home/dashboard?)

2. Make sure that **billing is enabled** for your Cloud project. Learn how to [check if billing is enabled on a project](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/verify-billing-enabled).

Then follow the following steps below to enable the API in your own Google Cloud project.

3. In the Cloud console, go to APIs & services for your project.

> [Go to APIs & Services](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis)

4. On the **Library page**, click **Private APIs**. If you don't see the API listed, that means you haven't been granted access to enable the API.
5. Click the API(**look for Storage Access API**) you want to enable. If you need help finding the API, use the search field.
6. On the page that displays information about the API, click **Enable**.

Reference:

- https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/run-gcloud-commands
- https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/enable-api#console

Answer (score 0):

It might be already enabled but there is a bug in this page so you need to re-authenticate

Open developer tools in your browser and select Network
you will find a line starting with `accounts.google.com` open it and authorize cloudshell.

[image]